# Is there a website that tell the rijal (mens) grading for shia?

Tags: hadith, shiism

salam alaikum
I need to know if there a website that tell rijal for shia hadith
since I don't find one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know one but its arabic only in this website
https://www.rejal.masaha.org/